# Get first element from PySpark data frame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, extract

I have a PySpark data frame which only contains one element. How can I extract the number from the data frame?

For the example, how can I get the number 5.0 from the PySpark data frame?

```
+-----------------+
|        count    |
+-----------------+
|        5.0      |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: `df.collect()[0][0]` where `[0][0]` is for the first row-column extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several alternatives:

```py
df.head()[0]
df.head().count
df.head()['count']
```

`first` does the same, but `head` is 1 letter shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

```py
sc.parallelize([5.0]).collect()

[5.0]
```